# What is the cause of too much recursion?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an in browser math game, but I am running into an error of too much recursion but I am unable to locate the cause.

Any help or advice with debugging would be greatly appreciated.

https://pastebin.com/ugTk00S1

HTML

```
<body>
    <label id="question"></label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="answer">
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <label id="correct">Correct: 0</label>
    <br><br>
    <label id="incorrect">Incorrect: 0</label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" id="enterButton" value="E N T E R" />
</body>
```

Javascript

evalFunction is called when the button is clicked, and passes the 2 numbers and the sign value

It seems that the button is pressed when the page loads, but even when the input it blank is still has some correct answers. About 1/21 of the time so because all answers fall between 0 and 20 it may be that it is counting no answer as 0, which it was not doing previously.

```
            var enterButton = document.createElement('enterButton');
        enterButton.onclick = evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);
```

Comment: please paste your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have a problem because you're suddendly calling the function `evalFunction`*

```
var enterButton = document.createElement('enterButton');
enterButton.onclick = evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);
                      ^
```

*You need to assign the function to the attribute `onclick`*

```
var enterButton = document.createElement('enterButton');
enterButton.onclick = function() {
   evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);
};
```

*Or you can bind the event `click` using the function `addEventListener`*

```
var enterButton = document.createElement('enterButton');
enterButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);
});
```

Comment: Thank you this stopped the recursion. I am still having trouble with passing the variable to the evalFunction though. I set an alert before and after trying to pass the varables to test if it is activating evalFunction, but it does not go off.

Comment: This worked for me. 
        <input type="button" id="enterButton" value="E N T E R"/>
    document.getElementById("enterButton").addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
            evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);
        }, false);

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have execute `mathFunction` as such: `window.onload = mathFunction();` which will cause it to execute when the window is loaded. In that mathFunction you're configuring a button with `onclick`:

```
enterButton.onclick = evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);
```

However this will put the value of `evalFunction` in the `onclick` since it will execute immediately because it's not written correctly. Below is an example which would be correct.

```
enterButton.onclick = function(){evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);};
```

Comment: Thank you this stopped the recursion. I am still having trouble with passing the variable to the evalFunction though. I set an alert before and after trying to pass the variables to test if it is activating evalFunction, but it does not go off.